# multi-line output through SSH command

Tags: ssh, awk

I need a multi-line output over SSH remote command.

If I use this command on the local machine, I have correct output:

```
sudo docker stats --no-stream container1 container2 container3 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$9,'$(date +%s)'}}'

container1 72.85 1471958776
container2 14.83 1471958776
container3 9.362 1471958776
```

If launched remotely, it strips the line feeds:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -i key.pem user@host sudo docker stats --no-stream container1 container2 container3 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1,$9,'$(date +%s)'}}'

container1 72.85 1471957426 container2 14.83 1471957426 container3 9.362 1471957426
```

How can I get the same result as the local output, one per line?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be due to the `-t` argument to `ssh`. This forces a tty allocation and requests terminal output: colors, control sequences. But then, instead of displaying the output on your local terminal (which would know how to do it), you are instead piping it into `awk`. (To see exactly what you're getting from `ssh`, use `cat -A` instead of `awk`.) You should either avoid `-t` when the output is not destined for a terminal, or else attempt to clean up the hidden control sequences. The latter is harder to do, so I suggest the former.

Comment: I have tried to disable the `requiretty` option to `/etc/sudoers` and launch a command without `-t` and have the same problem....how can use `cat` instead of `awk`?

Comment: `ssh ... | cat -A` will show non-printable characters that are received locally from the remote command.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with `xargs` command:

```
echo ${RESULTS} | xargs -n3
```